# GLSL - Wrong data in vertex attribute

Tags: android, glsl, opengl-es-2.0, vbo, vertex-shader

I have already lost 2 days trying to figure out on this issue, but with no use.

I have written a collada animation renderer using opengles2.0 for android; using shader for skinning. The code is almost complete and it runs just fine on my HTC DesireS.

But, when I try to run the same on a tridernt SetTopBox with PowerVR chipset, my geometry is not displayed. After a day of debugging, I found out that it is happening because I am getting != -1 as bone matrix indeices in the shader.

I verified that it is == -1 in my phone; but is != -1 in the SetTopBox.

What could possibly be wrong? 
Please save me from this big trouble.

Sorry for not puttingup the code. 
Here is the vertex shader. I am expecting vec2(boneIndices) to have -1 in [0] as well as [1]; but is not so on Powervr.

```
attribute vec4 vPosition;
attribute vec2 vTexCoord;
attribute vec2 boneIndices;
attribute vec2 boneWeights;

uniform mat4 boneMatrices[BNCNT];

uniform mat4 modelMatrix;
uniform mat4 viewMatrix;
uniform mat4 projectionMatrix;

varying mediump vec2 fTexCoord;
varying mediump vec3 col;

void main(){
    vec4 tempPosition = vPosition;
    int index = int(boneIndices.x);
    col = vec3(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    if(index >= 0){
        col.y = 1.0;
        tempPosition = (boneMatrices[index] * vPosition) * boneWeights.x;
    }
    index = int(boneIndices.y);
    if(index >= 0){
        col.z = 1.0;
        tempPosition = (boneMatrices[index] * vPosition) * boneWeights.y + tempPosition;
    }
    gl_Position = projectionMatrix * viewMatrix * modelMatrix * tempPosition;

    fTexCoord = vTexCoord;
}
```

---

setting up the attribute pointers

```
glVertexAttribPointer(position, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 13*sizeof(GLfloat), 0);
glVertexAttribPointer(texCoord, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 13*sizeof(GLfloat), (GLvoid*)(3*sizeof(GLfloat)));
glVertexAttribPointer(boneIndices, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 13*sizeof(GLfloat), (GLvoid*)(9*sizeof(GLfloat)));
glVertexAttribPointer(boneWeights, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 13*sizeof(GLfloat), (GLvoid*)(11*sizeof(GLfloat)));
glEnableVertexAttribArray(position);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(texCoord);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(boneIndices);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(boneWeights);
```

---

my vertex and index buffers

```
GLfloat vertices[13*6] =
{-0.5*size, -0.5*size, 0, 0,1, 1,1,1,1, -1,-1, 0,0,                                 
 -0.5*size,  0.5*size, 0, 0,0, 1,1,1,1, -1,-1, 0,0, 
  0.5*size,  0.5*size, 0, 1,0, 1,1,1,1, -1,-1, 0,0, 

 -0.5*size, -0.5*size, 0, 0,1, 1,1,1,1, -1,-1, 0,0, 
  0.5*size,  0.5*size, 0, 1,0, 1,1,1,1, -1,-1, 0,0, 
0.5*size, -0.5*size, 0, 1,1, 1,1,1,1, -1,-1, 0,0 };

GLushort indices[]= {0,1,2, 3,4,5};
```

---

I am expecting the indices to be -1 in the shader; but they are not.

Comment: What is getting -1? An attribute index? Could you show us some code?

Comment: Sorry for not putting up the code.

Comment: So... are you going to show us some code?

Comment: Sorry, I was new to Stackoverflow and accidentally posted that comment. The code is now added in the original question.

Comment: _Data, data, data_ ;) Modify the vertices array to some checkerboard pattern (e.g. `0.0f, 0.33f, 0.66f, 1.0f, 0.66f, ...` and at the end of the shader, set `col` according to boneIndices somehow. Then, check if what you see matches what you expect, or if there is anything dubious. The idea is to learn about the actual operation of the device. Don't know if this will work, though...

Comment: I am not sure how to really try it out...  btw will endianess have something to do with this problem I am facing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After days of frustration, **I finally found the problem by myself**.

The culprit was the "int()" function call, which was returning 0 even if I specify -1.
The observed behavior is that it returns
0 for -1
-1 for -2
-2 for -3 and like...

I am not sure if this is a driver/hw bug, or if it is because of the floating point representation where -1 is represented as something like "-.9999999"

Can anybody shed a little more light on this?

Comment: I'm experiencing this issue as well.  What was your actual solution in the end?